# ResponseEntity in Optional as ok or noContent, depending if present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im currently returning my content in this way:

```
Optional<String> data = Optional.of("bla");
Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> response = data.map(ResponseEntity::ok);
return response.orElse(ResponseEntity::noContent);
```

is there a way to combine the `map` with the `orElse` without saving them into a variable first?

(something like this, but without the cast problems)

```
Optional<String> data = Optional.of("bla");
return data.map(ResponseEntity::ok) // Type: ResponseEntity<String>
  .orElse(ResponseEntity::noContent); // Type: ResponseEntity<?> => Cast Error
```

This is a similar problem to

```
Optional.of<Object>("bla").orElse(2);
```

but I don't know how how to do this with a map

```
Optional.of("bla")
        .<ResponseEntity<?>>map(ResponseEntity::ok)
        .orElse(ResponseEntity::noContent);
```

does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

return data.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.noContent().build());

Comment: Oh, I forgot the .build(); Ty, a lot

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what your problem is exactly.

Can't you just do something like this:

```
return Optional.of("bla")
    .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
    .orElse(ResponseEntity::noContent);
```

Comment: No, this is not possible, because the first map makes it a Optional<ResponseEntity<String>> and ResponseEntity.noContent() is of type ResponseEntity<?> and therefore not castable.

It would be the same like 
Optional.of("bla").orElse(2); 

Which has to be rewritten to
Optional<Object> data = Optional.of("bla");
return data.orElse(2);

or return Optional.<Object>of("bla").orElse(2);